# UISplitViewController viewWillDisappear

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, uisplitviewcontroller

I created the sample project from "Master-Detail Application" for iPad.

What I found out, that `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` are never called in `DetailViewController`.

Is it possible to fix that?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the detail view is never removed from the screen, it's content is just changed. That's the reason those methods are not called.

Maybe you need to detect when the content is changed instead.

For example, when:

```
- (void)configureView
```

It's called, using the sample Master-Detail app for iPad.

Comment: It is quite inconvenient to use configureView. I think I'll switch to one of the reveal view controllers instead.